# Transfer files from Azure PaaS VM to IaaS VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

On an Azure PaaS virtual machine I have some rather large files that I would like to transfer to an Azure IaaS virtual machine.  I can think of a few ways to do this: FTP, SMB, but I have no idea which method would be the "best".

Has anyone done this before?  Any suggestions to get me started?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using Azure blob storage?  It's as fast as using a local drive if you're in the same data center.  If you need to transfer these files programmatically, there is a REST-based API or .NET wrappers around it.

Otherwise, you can just use any one of the free or commercial tools to do so, like this one:
http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/

Comment: Yes, the mounted data disk VHDs are backed by blob storage.  I have individual files on one VHD blob that I'd like to transfer to another VHD blog on another VM.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood my response.  You can transfer individual files from one VM to another VM via the blob storage.

Comment: How can you do this?  Blob storage doesn't know anything about what it's storing, which in this case is a VHD with an NTFS file structure.  I'd like to transfer one file on a VHD; e.g. e:\somedirectory\foo.jpg

Comment: Check out the link to the tool that I mentioned.  All you have to do is run that tool on each VM and connect it to the same storage account.  Upload files from one account and download them from another

Comment: Ah, sorry, I understand what you're saying now.  This is a fantastic idea and is probably the most straight forward way to achieve what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Transferring files to an IaaS VM can be a bit of a pain as there's no elegant way to do it that I can tell.  The options we've used are:

1. FTP onto the machine by running an FTP server application inside the VM
2. Open an RDP connection with a shared clipboard and/or hard disks and copy the file(s)
3. Create a VPN and copy the files via UNC
4. Use the new **Azure File Service** feature recently announced into preview ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx) then use AzCopy (http://aka.ms/azcopy) to transfer the files into blob storage

Option 4 is probably the most elegant, but equally the most complicated, as it involves signing up for the feature preview then getting everything working.  It would however allow you to access the files via IaaS across multiple machines as well as accessing the files via any PaaS solutions you might have.